# In front of a line

Tags: word-usage, ambiguity

Say there's a line marked horizontally on the ground, like the ones in the subway. If you were to say, "I'm in front of the line", would you be standing behind it, past it, or on it?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As is usually the case, everything depends on context. Use a different expression if you require clarity, or define what front and back are in relation to if you with to use this one.

Comment: If you say "I'm in front of the line" then, from your perspective, you would be in front of it... But as a line doesn't have a "front" as such, "in front" and "behind" will be defined relative to something else. This something else may depend on the point of view or position of each individual person, or there may be a widely accepted convention.  "like the ones in the subway" is a little vague for me to be sure, but I suspect [Pam's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/434274/91730) has interpreted it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

In front and behind tend to be opposites. Thesaurus.com lists "front" as an antonym of "behind". I don’t think you can be both in front of and behind the same thing. If you are in front of the line, then the line is behind you (unless you turn around!).

Similarly, if you are "on" the line, then you are not in front of it.

If you pass the line, the it is behind you, in your past. That means you have crossed it.

With regards to the subway, it is assumed that if you are waiting on a platform and can hear the announcements, you are waiting to board a train. You intend to move forward and cross the line. So right now the line is in front of you as you face it and you are asked to wait behind the line.